# Reasons to upgrade from 2.2.2 to 2.3.10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What are the big changes from 2.2.2 to 2.3.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes from 2.2 to 2.3:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html